# What kind of screwdrivers can unscrew these screws?

Tags: screws, screwdriver

I have used this laptop fan cooler pad for almost two years: Cooler Master NotePal X-Slim Ultra-Slim Laptop Cooling Pad with 160mm Fan (R9-NBC-XSLI-GP) [https://www.amazon.com/gp/aw/d/B005C31HC0](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B005C31HC0)?

Since a month ago, the fan has stopped rotating.

I have opened up its external screen, see the picture in the first link at the end of the post. I don't find any visible tear and worn with the usb power chord exposed outside.

I want to check what's underneath the fan, but do I need to remove the fan?

How can I remove the fan?

- The screw-like things under the fan aren't actually screws that my screwdrivers can fit into, see the pictures in the second and third links at the end of the post.  What kinds of screwdrivers can unscrew the "screws"?
- I also tried to pull the fan out directly, but it didn't detach and I was afraid of breaking anything and gave up.

I would appreciate your help. Thanks!

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: The pictures aren't all that clear even if I zoom in. It's there any sign that they actually have screw threads? Is there any non-rotationally-symmetric feature on the heads? Age they even made of metal? I've seen plastic studs melted into rivets that would have to be drilled out.

Answer (score 6):

The picture may say it all, I think you will be hard pressed to find a replacement fan. There is not a whole lot to do with these type of fans.

[image: Cooler]